# How to re-order items inside of an Angular Controller? Not using orderBy in the markup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

http://plnkr.co/edit/apwAQG9tczOUckbc9bya?p=preview

[image]

I'm trying to re-order my li items in the plnkr above without resorting to the `ng-repeat` `| orderBy:predicate:reverse` syntax in the markup.

Reason being is that I load new items based on different order criteria into the same list so I can't have something static.

My current list looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="t in tags" ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(t)">
      <div class="tag-container">
        <div class="tag border1"
             ng-mouseover="showTagDetails(t)">{{t.name}} | {{t.tweets}}</div>
        <tag-details tag="t"></tag-details>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The button I've added to sort the items inside of the controller:

```
<button ng-click="reOrderByTweets()">Order by Tweets</button>
```

The function I have so far, however unsure as to how to call the orderBy code within the controller:

```
function reOrderByTweets() {
    vs.orderReverse = !vs.orderReverse;
    console.log('vs.orderReverse = ', vs.orderReverse);
}
```

Comment: the decision to use `orderBy` or not should not be only decided by preference: do you actually need to persist the ordering information in the underlying data when the UI changes? Otherwise doing it in the view layer (with orderBy) seems like the more appropriate thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$filter` as described in the angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Here is your updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iYYOhg2IRT9ZV9QHBzRY?p=preview) with filter in js.

But I would also prefer to do it in markup but it doesn't really matter where you do the filtering.

Please also have a look at a simplified demo for filtering in js below.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope, $filter) {
    var vm = this;
    this.items = [{
        name: 'test1'
    }, {
        name: 'test2'
    }, {
        name: 'test3'
    }];
    this.orderReverse = false;

    this.changeOrder = function () {
        console.log('change order');
        vm.orderReverse = !vm.orderReverse;
        vm.items = $filter('orderBy')(vm.items, 'name', vm.orderReverse);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.changeOrder()">re-order</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @AWolf! I think I'm leaning on your solution, I re-forked that plunkr and added some more data to better reflect the problem I'm trying to solve here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q34J9szbLeGgc4jkcNUM?p=preview  Any idea why it's sorting the way it is? Instead of tweets or vols going from high to low, or low to high, the numbers don't seem to make sense.

Comment: Thanks and new question posted! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298987/why-are-my-ng-repeat-items-not-filtering-as-expected-here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question correctly, it's just:

Controller:

```
$scope.order = 'tweets';
function reOrderByTweets() {
    $scope.order = $scope.order === 'tweets' ? '-tweets' : 'tweets';
}
```

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tags | orderBy: order">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CROId13Fnik9inPg3EEu?p=preview);

Comment: Thanks, but I forked AWolf's plunkr below and adding `vol` to better reflect the problem I'm trying to solve http://plnkr.co/edit/Q34J9szbLeGgc4jkcNUM?p=preview