# Why are my ng-repeat items not filtering as expected here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

**Plnkr:** **http://plnkr.co/edit/Q34J9szbLeGgc4jkcNUM?p=preview**

I have a simple Array called tags, which contains 4 objects with a tweets value and vol value.

[image]

When I click the **Order by Tweets**, or **Order by Vol** buttons I expect the numbers to make sense, like going from high to low or low to high, but the numbers are out of order.

**Markup:**

```
 <div class="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebar">
  <header class="my-header">
    <button ng-click="reOrderByTweets()">Order by Tweets</button>
    <button ng-click="reOrderByVol()">Order by Vol</button>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="t in tags" ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(t)">
      <div class="tag-container">
        <div class="tag border1"
             ng-mouseover="showTagDetails(t)">{{t.name}} | tweets: {{t.tweets}} | vol: {{t.vol}}</div>
        <tag-details tag="t"></tag-details>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.tags.push(
  {
    name: 'Item 1 ', 
    tweets: '412',
    vol: '50'
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 2 ', 
    tweets: '10',
    vol: '500'
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 3 ', 
    tweets: '67',
    vol: '5'
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 4 ', 
    tweets: '0',
    vol: '30'
  }
);
```

The functions:

```
function reOrderByTweets() {
    console.log('reOrderByTweets');
    vs.orderReverse = !vs.orderReverse;
    $scope.tags = $filter('orderBy')($scope.tags, 'tweets', vs.orderReverse);
    console.log('vs.orderReverse = ', vs.orderReverse); // true or false
    console.log('$scope.tags = ', $scope.tags);
}

function reOrderByVol() {
    console.log('reOrderByVol');
    vs.orderReverse = !vs.orderReverse;
    $scope.tags = $filter('orderBy')($scope.tags, 'vol', vs.orderReverse);
    console.log('vs.orderReverse = ', vs.orderReverse); // true or false
    console.log('$scope.tags = ', $scope.tags);
}
```

As you can see the screenshot below, while ordering by **Vol**. The item with `vol:5` should come last after `vol:30`

[image]

---

**Update:** Looks like it's only filtering on the first digit in the numbers? Why would it not take the entire number?

Filtering by tweets clicked once:

[image]

Filtering by tweets clicked a 2nd time:

[image]

Comment: show template please

Comment: @sjt003 markup added, I purposely do not want to have orderBy in the markup

Comment: @LeonGaban you're ordering by the text value. Vol is a text value not a number. So its ordering by alphabetical order.

Comment: @Phill you are correct! Sigh, want to post the answer.. or should I delete this as it's a syntax or rather a type error.

Comment: Also do angular.element($0).scope to see if your $scope.tags is actually changing--it would be better to refer to it within an object.

Comment: Can delete or give me e-points :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're ordering by a string value which is done by alphabetical order.

'10'
'5'
'30'

The string order of this is 10 / 30 / 5.

Changing your 'vol' & 'tweets' to numbers:

```
  $scope.tags.push(
    {
      name: 'Item 1 ', 
      tweets: 412,
      vol: 50
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 2 ', 
      tweets: 10,
      vol: 216
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 3 ', 
      tweets: 67,
      vol: 15
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 4 ', 
      tweets: 0,
      vol: 30
    }
  );
```

Sorts your tweets correctly.

[image]

Comment: For completeness, if the data are strings and couldn't be changed. You could also add `getter` function to the `$filter` service and use `parseInt(tag.tweets)` to convert the string of tweet into an integer. See this example [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/REhkWo6gaFPPkik7oUgE?p=preview).